# Problem with running GUI applications inside docker containers

Tags: python, docker, pyqt5, dockerfile, xvfb

I have been trying to run a GUI application inside a docker container and have spent a lot of time getting it to work but it's not working. This is how I try to run the docker container:

```
sudo docker run -it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY myfirstdocker
```

I have also tried this way and many other ways:

```
sudo docker run -it myfirstdoocker
```

But I get this error message:

```
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display unix:0
enter code here
```

The application is written in python and I'm installing both pyqt5, xvfb and all other dependencies you see below. I've tried setting the DISPLAY to 0, using ENV QT_QPA_PLATFORM offscreen, running the docker container with different commands but still I get the above error message. I have both my app scripts and the dockerfile in the same folder and have ubuntu operating system.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install \
  -y --no-install-recommends python3 python3-virtualenv

COPY . .
ADD . .

RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --pre scapy[complete]
RUN pip install yapf
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pyqt5  
RUN apt-get install -y xvfb
RUN apt-get install -y qtbase5-dev
RUN apt-get install -y python-setuptools 

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libegl1-mesa \
        libgl1-mesa-dri \
        x11-xserver-utils \
        libxkbcommon-x11-0 \
        x11-utils \
        libnss3 \
        libasound2 \
    libxcb-xinerama0 \
    xserver-common

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libgstreamer1.0-0 \
        gstreamer1.0-plugins-base \
        gstreamer1.0-plugins-good \
        gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad \
        gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly \
        gstreamer1.0-libav \
        gstreamer1.0-doc \
        gstreamer1.0-tools \
        libpulse-mainloop-glib0 \
        alsa-base \
        alsa-utils \
        pulseaudio

 ENV DISPLAY=:0
 ENV SCREEN=0
 ENV DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null
 ENV XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000

 RUN mkdir -p -m 0700 $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR && chown -R $USERNAME:users $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR

ENV QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=0
ENV QT_VERBOSE true
ENV QT_TESTING true

CMD [ "python3", "./my_app.py" ]
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: what is your OS, try execute `xhost +` before `sudo docker run -it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY myfirstdocker
`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I’ve tried this as well but it didn’t work. My OS is Ubuntu 18.04